# AccessibilityService not connect sometimes and need to reboot phone

Tags: accessibilityservice

I have implemented an AccessibilityService application in Android, it works well, but sometimes, I found it isn't take affect, that is to say, seems AccessibilityService cannot be connected, but after reboot my phone, everything goes ok again.
by the way, my phone is Android 6.0 (CM13).
Anyone encounter the same problem and can give me a hand to how

Comment: Yes me too have same problem you have to register reboot receiver